# BlogEngine xml format practicality

Tags: blogengine.net

How practical is using xml format storage of BlogEngine's posts, without adversely affecting its performance ? 
For very small number of posts, definitely its a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

XML storage is good for websites that have less than 100 [Posts(and/or)Pages].
If you have more than 100 then the site is going to slow down the server.

Also if the website is a "members" based site under 300 members for xml.

http://blogengine.codeplex.com/discussions/257560

http://blogengine.codeplex.com/discussions/253252